# How do I get javascript to run on my index.html file in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I have launched an EC2 instance. In the user data I have the following script, but my javascript wont run. I only see the text. What should I do? I ran this locally and works as expected in my browser.

```
#!/bin/bash

# get admin privileges
sudo su

# install httpd (Linux 2 version)
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd.x86_64
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
echo "<body>
    Text here
    <br>
    <p id="quote"></p>
    <script>
        var affirmArray = [
            "text here", 
            "text here", 
            "text here", 
            "text here"
        ];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * affirmArray.length);

        function showquote(){
            document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = affirmArray[rand];
        }
        showquote();
    </script>
</body>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking to a path or host of a javascript library on your server, you need to do this before you reference javascript functions.

download and host it yourself or get a link to a minified version of a javascript library.

Include something like this before you run your script you got currently.

```
<script>file path/ or http://linkToMinifiedVersion</script>
```